# What's the Differential of this Map $f:S^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

$f:S^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined as $f(x,y,z,w)=x+zw$, where $S^3= \{(x,y,z,w) | x^2 +y^2 +z^2 +w^2 =1\}$

I tried using a stereographic chart but that got ugly. The function is so simple I was hoping there would be a better way to compute it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean the map $f_* : TS^3 \to T\mathbb{R}$? $f$ extends to a function $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$, so just find the differential of that.

In more detail, let $g$ be said extension, and let $i$ be the inclusion $S^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4$. Then,

$$ g_* = f_* \circ i_* $$

and $i_*$ is very simple.

---

You mean the exterior derivative $\mathrm{d}f$? $f$ extends to a scalar field on $\mathbb{R}^4$, so find the exterior derivative of that.

In more detail, let $g$ be said extension, and let $i$ be the inclusion $S^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4$. Then,

$$ i^*\mathrm{d}g = \mathrm{d}f $$

and $i^*$ is very simple.

Comment: Yep, I mean the map $f_*$ on the tangent space.What you're saying makes sense, but what am I doing wrong here: For a simpler example, take $f:S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ were $f(x,y)=2x^2 +y$. Then $f_*=[4x \hspace{2mm} 1]$, which has rank=1 and so no critical points. But if I use a chart: $x=\cos \theta, y=\sin \theta$ then I get $f_*=-4 \cos \theta \sin \theta + \cos \theta$ and this has multiple critical points.

Comment: Compare with the matrix $\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right]$ which has rank $1$, but the linear transformation it induces on the subspace of vectors of the form $(0,x)$ actually has rank zero. You get the same deal here: at some points, multiplication by $[4x\ 1]$ is a rank-zero map on the tangent space to $S^1$ (when viewed as a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: Ah, I see, so I am looking for zeros of $< [4x \hspace{2mm} 1],[1,\pm x(1-x^2)^{-1/2}]>$. Thanks! I guess I need to similarly above.

Comment: Hmm I think I'm having a little trouble doing this above. I want to look at the vectors that span the tangent space, right? So if I let $(x,y,z,w)=(x, \pm (1-x^2 -z^2 -w^2)^{1/2}, z,w)$ then taking partials wrt to $x,z,$ and $w$ will give me basis I believe. These are $[1\hspace{2mm} dy/dx \hspace{2mm} 0 \hspace{2mm}0], [0\hspace{2mm} dy/dz \hspace{2mm} 1\hspace{2mm}0], [0 \hspace{2mm} dy/dw \hspace{2mm} 0 \hspace{2mm}1]$ I want each of these to be 0 when I multiply them by $f_*=[1\hspace{2mm} 0 \hspace{2mm} w \hspace{2mm}z]$. But this gives me $z=w=0$ and $1=0$?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're looking for; are you trying to find a point where $f_*$ is the zero map on the tangent space? Then as your calculation shows, this never happens on the domain where those derivatives are well-defined, although you'll have to do some more work to work out where those derivatives are not well-defined.

Comment: However, in this case we can "cheat" using four-dimensional Euclidean geometry: the points where $f_*$ is the zero map on the tangent space to the sphere is the same as those points where the vector $f_*^T$ is perpendicular to the $3$-sphere: that is those points $P$ at which $f_*^T$ is a multiple of the vector from the origin to $P$.

Comment: The reason I use the transpose is as follows: $f_*$ is a linear map, and its computation doesn't involve any inner products or anything -- we can express it as a covector field, and in coordinates, it is a *row* vector, whereas vector fields are supposed to be *column* vectors. The (metric) transpose of $f_*$ is the vector field with the property that $f_* v = \langle f_*^T, v \rangle$ for all vector fields $v$.

Comment: Thanks for all those comments- extremely helpful, I haven't seen it explained like that before. If I am understanding correctly, there are then two critcal points: $(\pm 1, 0,0,0)$